# Can't deploy Magento2 theme locally on MAMP

Tags: magento2, mamp, bin-magento

I am supposed to rework a front end design of an existing Magento2 website, I already have a local installation of Magento2 on MAMP with composer. I used my project's git repo so all the files in app/design are there.

I am coming from Wordpress so I read up the documentation and I understand I have to use `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy` to make the theme visible but while that command works on the development server it doesn't work on the local MAMP, same as any other bin/magento command (like cache:clean or setup:install etc - after a while I started trying randomly).

I was searching for this on stack forums and several people suggested to manually remove `var/di`, `var/cache`, `var/page_cache` and `var/generation`, which I did, and now the frontend and Magento backend are both down. The bin/magento commands still don't work.

How can I deploy Magento2 theme on localhost on a MAMP server?

The error:

```
[InvalidArgumentException]
There are no commands defined in the "setup:static-content" namespace.
Did you mean one of these?
  setup
  setup:config
  setup:cron
  setup:db-data
  setup:db-schema
  setup:db
  setup:di
  setup:performance
  setup:store-config
```

when I run one of the suggestions I get analogous error:

```
[InvalidArgumentException]
 Command "setup:store-config" is not defined.
 Did you mean one of these?
  setup:store-config:set
  setup:backup
  setup:config:set
  setup:cron:run
  setup:db-data:upgrade
  setup:db-schema:upgrade
  setup:db:status
  setup:di:compile
  setup:performance:generate-fixtures
  setup:install
  setup:rollback
  setup:upgrade
  setup:uninstall
```

Comment: There are no commands defined in the "setup:static-content" namespace.!!! please use  php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure you have your  **app/etc/config.php** and **app/etc/env.php** files
2. give full permission to **var** and **pub** folders
   sudo chmod 777 -R var pub

Answer (score -1):

Sheshgiri Anvekar but that's what I used. it's written in the question.

> I understand I have to use php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy